# Why do they say 'Why would I do that' instead of "'Why would I have done that?"

Tags: present-perfect, conditional-constructions, present-tense

It is often said when someone accuses you of doing something that you haven't done

For example:

James: You stole my bank card!

Ruth: No, I didn't. Why would I do that? (it won't work for me
because I dont know what your pin code is)

It asks for the hypothetical reasons for doing something
- that what could've led him to do that

Furthermore, by saying this, the person is making a statement that it is so unlikely of him to do that

But what I don't understand is why do people say "Why would I do that" instead of "Why would I have done that?". (as the action was done in the past)

Comment: Do not delete your questions after they receive an answer. The answers on this site are intended to help more people than just the person who asked.

Answer (score 1):

**Why would I do that**? Expresses a general thought and is asking a general question. You express it in the present about a possibility.

**Why would I have done that?** Refers to a specific conditional time in the past when something actually might have happened. You express it about a **past possibility.** **No action is actually performed (done) in the past. The action is hypothetical about the past or a hypothetical past action.**

Both are correct, they just express different thoughts about a situation.

Comment: since no action was actually performed in the past (by the accused) . Why would I do that can work for an unperfomed past action?

Comment: @user82287 Yes, of course. The action is hypothetical in the past with past conditional.That is why it is called a conditional. It didn't occur. Doesn't your mother tongue have that possibility? :)

Comment: it does. what confused me is that isn't would've used for unreal situations too?

Comment: An unreal situation is the same thing as a hypothetical situation.

Comment: I know so would've can work here too. that's what I meant